# Is it possible to use an AND operator along with an ON in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have two tables:

[image: Table 1] [image: Table 2]

How would I select Moe from row 1 in the first table according to the Name AND Password of the Moe in table 2 (i.e, the Moe with "Helloworld" as password)

Basically, say as an example, I have T1 as first table and T2 as second,
How would I be able to select a whole row from T1 according to multiple conditions which match things from T2

---

I want it to do this:

```
SELECT  T2.Message,
      T1.Name,
      T1.Password
   FROM  T2
   JOIN  T1
   ON   T1.Name=T2.Name
   ORDER BY T1.timestamp
   DESC
```

---

But rather than checking only for Name, I would like for it to check for matching Name AND Password from both tables (so that it would show me the info of the Moe with the password "Helloworld").

---

Thanks and apologies ahead of time if I have not explained this properly.

Comment: Yes, you can use any boolean expression in the `ON` clause.  Two boolean expressions connect by `AND` is just another boolean expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is.

```
 SELECT  T2.Message,
    T1.Name,
    T1.Password
 FROM  T2
 JOIN  T1
 ON   T1.Name=T2.Name AND T2.IsMale = 1
 ORDER BY T1.timestamp
 DESC
```

Note the `AND T2.IsMale = 1` condition on top of `T1.Name=T2.Name`.